# XSLT Removing element with attribute but keep the children

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to transform xml/html files into dita files. I want to remove some nodes but keep their children. The difficulties are:

1. Node I want to remove have attributes. I get error:

   > An attribute node (class) cannot be created after a child of the
   >   containing element
2. And these attributes are unpredictable: I want to remove a variety of nodes, and I can't predict what kinds of attributes they have.
3. I don't know how deeply the node is nested in. It could be direct child of `<body>` or could be nested 4 or 5 levels down inside some other nodes.

**XML Example:**

```
<macro name="section">
   <rich-text-body>
      <macro name="column">
         <parameter name="width">80%</parameter>
         <rich-text-body>
            <p>horribly nested, <span>bulky</span> structure</p>
            <div>horribly nested, <span>bulky</span> structure</div>
         </rich-text-body>
      </macro>
   </rich-text-body>
</macro>
```

I want to remove the bulky macro tags, but keep only the children of the most inner `<rich-text-body>`. In this case, they are the `<p>` `<div>` tags.

This is as far as I got. The **XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="macro[@name='column' and parameter[@name='width'] ='80%']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to change the second apply to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` (i.e. at this level only apply to nodes), but I can't try this at the moment, which is why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks Jim! Totally didn't expect the answer to be this easy! This works great. Though, could you explain a little bit as how the `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` work? I mean, I thought this expression is used to select the child nodes and attributes, but apparently it has to do with the node I want to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, if you change

```
<xsl:template match="macro[@name='column' and parameter[@name='width'] ='80%']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="macro[@name='column' and parameter[@name='width'] ='80%']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

respectively the equivalent but shorter

```
<xsl:template match="macro[@name='column' and parameter[@name='width'] ='80%']">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

then you won't get any errors from the attributes of the `macro` element as they are not processed.

If you want to process them to add them to a different element then you need to show us exactly where you want to put them.

Comment: Thank you Martin! I just tested, both `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` works great!